# Combining queries on the same table in to one query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am trying to get some statistics from my MySQL Table and would like to keep it to a single query. Just don't know how (or if it is even possible). I have these two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `accept` 
FROM `status` 
WHERE `groupID` IN (98779,98780) 
  AND `group` = 'order' 
  AND `status` = 'accept'
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `price` 
FROM `status` 
WHERE `groupID` IN (98779, 98780) 
  AND `group` = 'quotation' 
  AND (`status` = 'final' OR `status` = 'manualprice')
```

My best suggestion is to combine them in a single `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `accept` 
     FROM `status`
     WHERE `groupID` IN (98779, 98780) AND `group` = 'order' AND `status` = 'accept') AS accept,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `price` 
     FROM `status` 
     WHERE `groupID` IN (98779, 98780) AND `group` = 'quotation' AND (`status` = 'final' OR `status` = 'manualprice')) AS price
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    sum(if(`group` = 'order' AND `status` = 'accept', 1,0)) as `accept`,
    sum(if(`group` = 'quotation' AND (`status` = 'final' OR `status` = 'manualprice'), 1,0)) as `price`
FROM 
    `status` 
WHERE 
    `groupID` IN (98779,98780) 
    AND `group` IN ('order', 'quotation') 
    AND `status` IN ('accept', 'final', 'manualprice')
```

**EDIT** this is basically the same as the other answer by 491243. I have used an additional if statement, seemingly is is not necessarily needed.

Comment: Thsi is very clever... so good there is more to learn. I was able to optimize my query by a factor 10. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

here's another way to do that,

```
SELECT  SUM(`group` = 'order' AND `status` = 'accept') AS `ACCEPT`,
        SUM(`group` = 'quotation' AND (`status` = 'final' OR `status` = 'manualprice')) AS `PRICE`
FROM    `status`
WHERE   `groupID` IN (98779, 98780) AND
        `group` IN ('order', 'quotation') AND
        `status` IN ('accept', 'final', 'manualprice')
```